# GooglePlayStore suggestes optimizations (localization) but it's already localized

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

I get this message under the `Optimization tips` in the console:

[image]

the problem is that my app already contains the translations for FR and RU under `values-fr`  and `values-ru` and the store listings are also translated.

Another thing is that it also displays this:

[image]

but I don't have the app translated into Turkish :)

What is going on?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you are using any third-party library that is translated into Turkish, Google Play will think that your APK is translated into Turkish because the final APK contains Turkish strings. Google Play has no way to know that these strings come from a library and not your app.

There isn't much you can do about that, besides ignoring these messages.

Comment: Cool and nice dude :)

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much!